# Restricting jwt to device of generation nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt

I am generating a JWT token and verifying. I however have a problem which I am not sure how to solve. If I login on a postman and a token is generated, I want to prevent that same token from being used on another postman that means I want it to just be valid for calls made on that particular postman.

here is how I create my token

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id }, this.options.secret, { expiresIn: sessionDuration });
```

and verification is done like

```
jwt.verify(token,  this.options.secret)
```

Any pointer please.

Comment: How would the same token be sent to two clients?

Comment: Just basic copy and paste.

Comment: Like login in on the web and copying the token to postman. It should not work because the token was generated on the web.

Comment: Either you keep the token secure, or you use cookies/sessions. If you're worried about people copy/pasting tokens around I really think you need to rethink your application/workflow/security structure.

Comment: To add to what was said here. Don't try to prevent this, but instead try to figure out the underlying issue. What is the business reason you don't want a user to be able to copy and paste a token?

Comment: I was using hapi iron previously which gave me this level of security. Now it does not since I switched to JWT.

Comment: So it was an encrypted JWT? That doesn't prevent someone else from using it, just from reading it.

Comment: You could only use it on the device which it was created. What I need is how  to add a claim to the token that identifies the browser and/or the client.

Comment: There's no reliable way of doing this without some kind of client-side state (which again, can be copied). Whatever 'Iron' did must have given you a false sense of security.